# $rootScope.bodyClass not changing when the user goes to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I created a body class so I could use different CSS for different pages:

**homepage.js**

```
.controller('HomePageCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope,appService) {
   $rootScope.bodyClass = 'home-page'
```

**login.js:**

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($rootScope,$scope,appService,$window) {
   $rootScope.bodyClass = 'login-page'
```

**index.html:**

```
<body ng-app="yoApp" data-ng-class="bodyClass">
```

It works, but when I click to another page the previous class is maintained and I have to hit refresh to see the new class.

From Login page to Home page before refresh:

```
<body ng-app="yoApp" data-ng-class="bodyClass" class="ng-scope login-page">
```

Home page after refresh:

```
<body ng-app="yoApp" data-ng-class="bodyClass" class="ng-scope home-page">
```

What is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: can you attach a sample plunker or fiddle .

Comment: i tested in my local it seems to be changing without refresh . i used routing+ng-view combination with two different controllers .

Comment: @supercool Sorry, I'm a AnglularJS beginner. How did you exactly use `routing+ng-view`? (Or could you post your code as an answer?)

Comment: try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20367/ . to make fiddle functional you should be having html pages created .

Comment: @supercool why don't you put a plnkr of **routing+ng-view** ;-)

Comment: @VVK i added mate :) please find above now . #alex the basic idea in the above fiddle is you don't need to reload the page simply switch b/w views by you actions .

Comment: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fz3GriDhHeikXthm4Q4w?p=preview). Seems working (If you use `ng-route`).

Comment: @alexchenco yes indeed it is .

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute). It is an angular module to help you handle your routing. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am not sure how you can handle your routing here. Is there any more codes that we can look into ? (like when you declare your `angular.module("yoApp")`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working perfectly on my machine. I have created a sample application to test the scenario.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Into to Angular.js</title>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.2.17" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.17/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.11.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="container" ng-class="bodyClass">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h1>Intro to Angular</h1>
      <div id="view" ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**home.html**

```
<div id="login" class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    Welcome To Home Page.

  </div>
</div>
```

**login.html**

```
<div id="login" class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <form>
      <fieldset class="radius">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 columns">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="username" required="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 columns">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password" required="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <a href="#/home">Login</a>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      controller: 'LoginController'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      controller: 'HomeController'
    });
  })
  .controller('HomeController', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $rootScope.bodyClass = 'bg-info'
  })
  .controller('LoginController', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $rootScope.bodyClass = 'bg-danger'
  });
```

**[See plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/n9RSU7mkYmzSMtNEJ0Ko?p=preview)**.